# What's the easiest way to set up a relay chain locally with a couple of parachains?

Tags: polkadot, xcm

If I want to play about with cross-chain messaging (xcm) what's the best way to get an environment up and running?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One option is [polkadot-launch](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch), which will mount parachains for you into the relay chain.

For building the relay chain using the `cargo build --release --fast-runtime` (there is a `--profile production` rather than `--release` but the `lto` means that takes a lot longer to compile)

The mounting process that `polka-launch` uses assumes that the `sudo` pallet is included in the relay chain. At the moment there is no flag to achieve this - you will have to add it into the runtime `lib.rs` manually.

The relay-chain and the parachains have embedded the runtime wasm blob in them, but you can provide an alternative in raw JSON format if you want to start from an earlier version of the runtime.

Comment: I follow this [Substrate Tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/start-relay) and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Also the following are worthy mentions:

[parachain-launch](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/parachain-launch)

> parachain-launch is a script that generates a docker compose file allowing you to launch a testnet of multiple blockchain nodes.

[zombienet](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet)

> A cli tool to easily spawn ephemeral Polkadot/Substrate networks and perform tests against them.